# How to display compilation status in modified mode-line?

Tags: emacs, elisp, modeline

I modified my mode-line to appear cleaner. Sadly this prevents compilation buffers from displaying their exit status.

Normaly a failed compilation would display something like:

`(Compilation:exit [1])`

Through my modifications the the compilation status "exit [1]" is lost.

I defined major and minor modes as following:

```
(setq my-modeline-major-mode
  ;; major modes
  (list
    '(:eval (propertize "%m" 'face 'font-lock-string-face
                       'help-echo buffer-file-coding-system))))

(setq my-modeline-minor-modes
  ;; list of minor modes
  (list
    minor-mode-alist))
```

The modeline itself is structured as followed:

```
(setq-default mode-line-format
          (list
           "  ["
           my-modeline-major-mode
           "]["
           my-modeline-minor-modes
           "]"
           " %-" ;; fill with '-'
           ))
```

M-x customize-group compilation didn't provide any help.

Comment: Besides the mode-line-process, you should also add `global-mode-string`, which some modes use to display notifications. http://bruce-connor.github.io/emacs-online-documentation/Var/global-mode-string

Comment: And I'll take the chance to suggest you try out smart-mode-line. It has a cleaner look and let's you customize the mode-line with variables (instead of manually editing it), which should keep you from butchering useful information. :-) http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SmartModeLine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the value of `mode-line-process` in your custom mode line.  This seems to work:

```
(setq my-modeline-major-mode 
  ;; major modes
  (list
    '(:eval (propertize "%m" 'face 'font-lock-string-face
                       'help-echo buffer-file-coding-system))
    '("" mode-line-process)))
```